# Wish to find a list of integers and print if found in consecutive order

Tags: python

I wish to find if integers are in consecutive order in a list of inputs and if so print ok. I have tried

```
If 78,79,80 in listA:
Print("OK")
Else:
Print("Not ok")
```

Comment: should `ListA` contain those integers in strict order, like: `listA = [76,77,78,79,80,71]` ?

Comment: That's not even nearly Python code. Please follow an introductory tutorial: http://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F

Answer (score 0):

assuming the elements are in myList, you probably want something similar to this:

```
flag = True
for i, n in enumarate(myList[1:]):
   if n - myList[i] != 1:
      flat = Flase
      break

if flag:
   print 'OK'
else:
   print 'not ok'
```